# CSS - align menu options underneath header image

Tags: css

I am fairly new to this but I have created a header image and menu options and saved as .png images.

However, I cannot get the menu images to align to the left of the screen rather than hang out of the edge of the logo.

Here is a link to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lozjayne/xz99w/

And below is my code (sorry if it's really not that good)

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\Laura-Jayne\Documents\Crestel Website\cake\html\style.css" type="text/css">
<title>Cupcake Fairy</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="header-container">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo">
        <a href="#"><img src="C:\Users\Laura-Jayne\Documents\Crestel Website\cake\images\logo.png" /></a>
        </div>

        <div id="topnav">
        <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="C:\Users\Laura-Jayne\Documents\Crestel Website\cake\images\home.png" alt="home" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="C:\Users\Laura-Jayne\Documents\Crestel Website\cake\images\about.png" alt="about" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="C:\Users\Laura-Jayne\Documents\Crestel Website\cake\images\gallery.png" alt="gallery" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="C:\Users\Laura-Jayne\Documents\Crestel Website\cake\images\contact.png" alt="contact" /></a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
@charset "utf-8";

body {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

#header-container {
width: 100%;
height: 204px;
background-color: #e7fc56;
}

#header {
background-image: url("C:\Users\Laura-Jayne\Documents\Crestel Website\cake\images\header.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 1024px;
height: 204px;
margin: auto;
}

#logo{
float: left;
padding-top: 15px;
padding-left: 160px;
}



img {
border: none;
}

#topnav {

margin: auto;
height: 76px;
width: 1024px;
padding-top: 150px;
padding-left: 158px;
}



#topnav ul li
{
display: inline;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
width: 100px;
}

#topnav ul a {
text-decoration: none;
background: #e7fc56
float: left;
text-align: left;
}
```

Hope you are able to help,

Thankyou

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The menu is currently being pushed to the right, away from the left side of the screen, because it has `padding-left`. If you remove it, they will be aligned at the left side.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xz99w/1/)

```
#topnav {
    margin: auto;
    height: 76px;
    width: 1024px;
    padding-top: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Sorry only just managed to get back on the computer. The alteration works if I remove my image from the header. However when the image is there, the menu still only sits at the right hand side.

Comment: In the Fiddle I have linked to, the menu is aligned to the left, with and without the image. At least it is on Firefox and Chrome. What browser are you using?

Comment: Hi, thankyou for your help. It got me thinking and I altered the top padding of the navbar to a larger number which let it sit underneath the logo.

Comment: I'm happy to be of service. If you think it helped, could you click the checkmark or up arrow? Thanks!